# Why this Drawer Force Closes my app?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, forceclose, drawer

I haven't changed this part of my app, but after I rebuilt it, this force close displaying:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Child drawer has absolute gravity LEFT but this DrawerLayout already has a drawer view along that edge   Exception.
```

My Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/draw"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lin_hime_body"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/lay_title_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/frm_home"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/menu1">
    <include layout="@layout/lay_menu1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/menu2">
    <include layout="@layout/lay_menu2"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/menu3">
    <include layout="@layout/lay_menu3"/>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I got this exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Child drawer has absolute gravity
LEFT but this DrawerLayout already has a drawer view along that edge
                                                                            at
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1089)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18916)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5972)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18916)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5972)
                                                                            at
android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
                                                                            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18916)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5972)
                                                                            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                            at
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2693)
                                                                            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18916)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2218)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1294)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1536)
                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1185)
                                                                            at
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
                                                                            at
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:873)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:676)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                                            at
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:859)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                            at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace, please?

Comment: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout can have only two child layout

Comment: @SamuelRobert I Updated

Comment: I was getting this error because i tried to add more than one NavigationView 
  inside drawerLayout.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try This if it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/draw"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lin_hime_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                layout="@layout/lay_title_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frm_home"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu1"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/lay_menu1" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/menu2"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/lay_menu2" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/menu3"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/lay_menu3" />
    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: It solved! But now drawer is alwas open and wen i write drawer.close(menu1) app force closed.

Comment: try drawer.closeDrawers() to close the drawer

Answer (score 3):

Your DrawerLayout should have exactly 2 children and it should have gravity attribute which describes where you want the drawer to open from

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/your_actiivity_views_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```